# Windows 10 2004 ime indicator for romaji-kana is gone

Tags: windows-10, ime

My computer used to indicate whenever I switched from English to kana by a transparent grey-black box with a "A" or "あ”. This feature seems to be absent in the latest major update for windows 10. Can this feature be enabled through some setting or should I use the previous version of IME through "General/compatibility" settings. I couldn't find much info on this matter in both Japanese/English. [microsoft website](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/4462244/microsoft-ime#section-1) provides some information about the reformed menu and alert settings but I can't find any settings to change it.

Comment: just tested it: switching to "previous version of IME" does fix it, also the phrasing reeks of "deprecated" feature they're gonna drop soon... but the question remains, WHY is a simple visual feedback considered "incompatible" at all?!